# git difftool ignores textconv driver

Tags: git

`git diff` takes into account my [textconv driver](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv), but `git difftool -d --textconv` does not. Why? How to fix it?

My `~/.gitconfig` contains among other settings:

```
[diff]
    tool = default-difftool
[difftool "default-difftool"]
    cmd = vim -f '+next' '+execute \"DirDiff\" argv(0) argv(1)' $LOCAL $REMOTE '+syntax off'
[diff "ipynb"]
    textconv = nbcatsrc
```

And my `.gitattributes` is:

```
*.ipynb diff=ipynb
```

Comment: Did you set a particular difftool in your git settings ?

Comment: I have a similar problem -- I'm using textconv for ansible vault files, and using `vimdiff` for my diff tool. The textconv driver is used with `git diff`, but not with `git difftool` -- I'm getting a regular binary file diff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is git difftool on binaries possible? If so, how does one configure it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098218/is-git-difftool-on-binaries-possible-if-so-how-does-one-configure-it)

Answer (score 1):

It's true that `git difftool` ignores `textconv`.  An explanation and workaround is found here:

[Is git difftool on binaries possible? If so, how does one configure it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098218/is-git-difftool-on-binaries-possible-if-so-how-does-one-configure-it)