# Override .gitattributes from command line

Tags: git, vim, diff, gitattributes

Is there any way to temporarily override attributes in git, similarly to how `-c` can be used to override config options?

I would like to call `git diff` with a specific custom `textconv` command different from the one I normally use.

To make this more concrete: My actual use case is for Jupyter notebooks being edited in vim with the [`jupytext.vim` plugin](https://github.com/goerz/jupytext.vim).

My normal `~/.gitconfig` contains

```
[diff "jupyternotebook"]
    command = git-nbdiffdriver diff
```

that sets up [`nbdime`](https://nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as a diff driver, and then in `~/.gitattributes`:

```
*.ipynb diff=jupyternotebook
```

Now I'd like to have

```
[diff "jupytext"]
    textconv = jupytext --from=ipynb --to=md -o - <
```

(or something like that) in the git config, and have `git diff` act as if

```
*.ipynb diff=jupytext
```

was in .gitattributes.

I'd be open to adding the `[diff "jupytext"]` section permanently to my `~/.gitconfig`. However, using the "jupytext" driver instead of the default "jupyternotebook" must be temporary, based on a command line option passed to `git diff`.

Alternatively, I'd be OK with a command line option to `git diff` that forces it to use a different `~/.gitattributes` file that takes precedence over all other `.gitattributes` files (e.g. in the same directory).

Ultimately, the command line option is intended to go into the `g:gitgutter_diff_args` setting of [`vim-gitgutter`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter). I want to force the plugin to convert *.ipynb files differently from the way I would normally want to convert them with `nbdime`.

Comment: I could easily be missing something, but why not just override the `diff.jupyternotebook.command` config?

Comment: How about `git -c diff.jupytext.command='jupytext --from=ipynb --to=md -o - <' diff`?

Comment: I'd have to express it as a `command` instead of `textconv`, so it's a bit tricky, but I suppose it could work. There's no way to *disable* a configuration option via the command line, right? I'd still be interested in a general way to override `.gitattributes` settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar case where I wanted to switch a `textconv` filter on and off per run, rather than by file extension.  (I wanted to be able check sometimes if there are any changes that are not just a numeric change from  one value to another.)  The trick I found was to create a "default" case, which is always used, using `cat` for the textconv, and which I could then reassign with -c.

In my `~/.config/git/attributes` I have:

```
* diff=default
```

In my `~/.gitconfig` I have:

```
[diff "default"]
      textconv = cat
[diff "cat"]
      textconv = cat
[diff "nonums"]
      textconv = "f(){ gsed -E 's/[0-9]+/##/g'  \"$1\" ; }; f"
```

As well as this alias, letting me temporarily override the default case when desired by calling `git diff-nonums`.  (The alias allows any arguments that `git diff` allows.)

```
[alias]
    diff-nonums = !git -c diff.default.textconv=\"`git config diff.nonums.textconv`\" diff
```

For your case, I think you'd want to use difftool, rather than diff's `command` configuration, to toggle the actual command.  [The nbdime docs](https://test-nbdime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vcs.html) show they provide a script to write the needed configs (`git-nbdifftool config --enable [--global]`, and then can use `git difftool --tool=nbdime`)  Having done that, I believe you could set up the default+alias trick to switch both the tool and textconv to do what you need for either nbdiff or jupytext.

(See `man gitattributes`, a few paragraphs down, for places where the attributes file may be saved.  Note, I'm unclear about the difference between `command`, `external`, and `difftool`.  For instance, I didn't find an easy way just now to get external or command to use git itself.)

**edit** I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098218/is-git-difftool-on-binaries-possible-if-so-how-does-one-configure-it) that git largely intends you to choose between textconv versus external commands, rather than mix/chain (unfortunately).  I.e., the section in `man gitconfig` is called "Choosing textconv versus external diff".  The linked question suggests a workaround with temporary files.